# Conditions on $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty f(n)=-\frac12\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}(\cot(\pi z)+i)f(z)dz$

Tags: convergence-divergence, generating-functions, complex-integration, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

The [Ramanujan interpolation formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujansInterpolationFormula.html) states:

$$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) (-x)^n dx=\pi\csc(\pi s)f(-s)$$

therefore we use the [Mellin inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem):

$$\text M_s\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) (-x)^n\right)= \pi\csc(\pi s)f(-s)\iff \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) (-x)^n=\text M^{-1}_x( \pi\csc(\pi s)f(-s))$$

Next, one expands the inverse Mellin transform and sets $x=1$ or $f(n)x^n\to f(n)$. Finally, set the integration variable to $z$:

$$\boxed{\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) =\frac12\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}(-1)^{-z}\csc(\pi z)f(-z)dz=-\frac12\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}(\cot(\pi z)+i)f(z)dz}\tag 1$$

$(1)$ [works](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5Bln%28n%2B1%29%28-1%2F2%29%5En%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfty%7D%5D+-1%2F2+integral%5B%281%2F2%29%5E%28-%28i+s%2B1%2F3%29%29+csc%28pi*+%28i+s%2B1%2F3%29%29+ln%281-%28+i+s%2B1%2F3%29%29%2C%7Bs%2C-infty%2Cinfty%7D%5D) for $f(n)=\frac{\ln(n+1)}{(-2)^n}$ and other functions, but [diverges](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F2+integral%5Bcsc%28pi*+%28i+s%2B1%2F3%29%29+e%5E%28-%28+i+s%2B1%2F3%29%5E2%29%2C%7Bs%2C-10%2C10%7D%5D) $f(n)=e^{-n^2}$. The Mellin inversion article states gives conditions on the Mellin transform of $f(x)$, but not exactly $f(x)$ itself. What $(1)$’s conditions on $c,f(n)$?

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {f(n)}  = \frac{1}{{2{\rm i}}}\int_{ - 1/2 - {\rm i}\infty }^{ - 1/2 + {\rm i}\infty } {(\cot (\pi z) + {\rm i})f(z){\rm d}z} 
$$ seems more plausible for me. If you push the contour through the poles at the non-negative integers, you (at least formally) recover the sum on the left-hand side. I think analyticity and $f(z)=o(\mathrm{e}^{2\pi |\operatorname{Im}(z)|})$ is a sufficient condition.